# what is the difference between Azure Diagnostic settings (classic) UserObjectId vs principalId in AuthorizationDetail

Tags: azure

In azure Diagnostic settings (classic) version 2 what is the difference between UserObjectId and principals->ID in AuthorizationDetail fields

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**UserObjectId**: You can understand it as a user's unique identification identifier.

**principal id**: In Azure AD, users, groups, or service principals can all be called Azure AD principals. I’m not sure what your principal id specifically refers to. In my understanding, the principal id you said should refer to the service principal id. There are three types of service principal: application, managed identity, and legacy. Usually I will service principal is regarded as an application that has granted some permissions.

So, I think the difference between user object id and service principal id is that one is used to identify the user and the other is used to identify the application.